# Widget container to display SharePoint 2010 web parts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, widget

I have a requirement to build a widget container which is having behavior of expandable, collapsible, configurable widget title and content displayed in the widget with the configurable source as SharePoint WebParts (OOB and third party web parts).

Need to predefine the page layout to have widgets with 3 (rows) * 2 (columns) matrix, where user can configure each widget with the source as the SharePoint web part (document list, image rollover, third party forums web part etc.) and personalize their dashboard.

I don't know the possibility of implementing this requirement in SharePoint 2010 as i am new to it.

could anyone please help me in making me understand the implementation perspective of how we can build generic widget component with the source as a SharePoint web part.